# Gradient fill using Excel::Writer::XLSX module

Tags: excel, perl

In excel, we can apply a gradient fill to a shape color like below: [image]

So I'd like to know how to apply this attribute using in Perl module Excel::Writer::XLSX.

Comment: After a look at the documentation I'd say it is not supported yet. You could write a patch to do it and submit it to the author, though. Build one in Excel, unzip the xlsx-file, take a look at what the xml looks like (probably it's just a color-value) and add code for that to the module.

Comment: I can confirm that gradient fills are not supported by the module.

Comment: The primary focus of Excel::Writer::XLSX is to put tabular *data* into the .xlsx format. Fancy markup is a nice extra, but colors and graphs (usually) are no data themselves.